# Jquery .nextAll() is not working on hover

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, jquery-hover

I try to manipulate a certain class stacked in several parent div if the first div gets hovered.

And I am freaking because I can't get this to work

I created a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/h0153wja/9/

But here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="testkrams wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-4">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="cat-title">
        <h2> TestText TextTest with break</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.testkrams').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).nextAll(".cat-title").animate({
      marginLeft: '100px'
    }, 250);
  },
  function() {
    $(this).nextAll(".cat-title").animate({
      marginLeft: '0'
    }, 250);
  }
);
```

Any ideas?

Am I too tired?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nextAll()` looks for following siblings. The `.cat-title` element is a child of `.testkrams`. You should use `find()` instead:

```
$('.testkrams').hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".cat-title").animate({
        marginLeft: '100px'
    }, 250);
}, function() {
    $(this).find(".cat-title").animate({
        marginLeft: '0'
    }, 250);
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/h0153wja/12/)

Also note that you can achieve this in CSS alone using the `transition` rule:

```
.cat-title {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    max-width: 80%;
    z-index: 3;
    transition: margin-left .25s;
}
.testkrams:hover .cat-title {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/h0153wja/13/)

Comment: That works. Why on earth did I use a sibling selector instead of a child selector... Well I guess I'm too tired....
Thank you very much

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I also added an example using CSS alone, as JS code isn't necessarily required do what you need.

Comment: Yes, but that is actually not what I needed, I just broke down my code  for explanatory reasons ;)